# How to stop sending cookies to Server with each request

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cookies, browser

Consider I'm having >5KB size cookies, Which is a confidential data generating on client side  which no one else can see that data.

So I'm trying to restrict that data to send with request. Is there any way to tell that do not send this cookies with request ??

As per [cookies](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2965.html) spec

> When it sends a request to an origin server, the user agent includes a Cookie request header if it has stored cookies that are applicable to the request.

What is giving hope is in spec is **stored cookies that are applicable to the request.**

How to make it un- applicable to the request ??

So is this impossible ? Is there any way to configure web.xml in such a way  like we set `http-only`?

```
<session-config>
        <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

[The limit](http://browsercookielimits.x64.me/) for cookies per domain is about 4KB, which you already exceed.  Therefore, you ought to put all the confidential information into a session table instead of a cookie.

Comment: I'm aware of the limit, that is why the request is failing to go server. So I planned to restrict it to send via request. Thanks thought for that interesting link Will :)

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP specification states, that all cookie data need to be send with each request, because probably the server needs it. If you do not want that, then do not store data inside cookies, but use a different method of storing this sensitive information.

There is as well a good chance, that this sensitive information ends up in the access logs of the target server, another reason to not use cookies for that case.